# How to list all the current network connections for a given PID?

Tags: linux, process, open-files

If I have a PID, how can I then find all the connections that are open for that process?
I have tried with

```
netstat | grep $PID
```

but this does not seem to work. I need a command that will take that PID and print all the open network connections but I have no idea how. I have seen on other forms about strace but this does not make sense to me.

Comment: Use `lsof`. See `man lsof` for details.

Answer (score 12):

With `lsof`:

```
lsof -ai -p "$pid"
```

If you're not `root`, you'll only be able to get that for your processes.

Technically, that's only for the *internet* sockets (connected or not).

If you want all established *connections* (or associations), internet or not (like for Unix domain sockets), you could try (at least on Linux and with lsof 4.89):

```
lsof  -Ep "$pid" | grep -e '(ESTABLISHED)$' -e '->INO=.* '
```

For instance, for the process I use to write this answer, that gives:

```
firefox 6261 chazelas    3u     unix 0xffff88026785d000       0t0   741948 type=STREAM ->INO=743009 4244,dbus-daem,58u
firefox 6261 chazelas    4u     unix 0xffff88017194c000       0t0   741280 type=STREAM ->INO=742999 3575,Xorg,57u
firefox 6261 chazelas    6u     unix 0xffff8802f544d400       0t0   743000 type=STREAM ->INO=741281 4244,dbus-daem,56u
firefox 6261 chazelas   11u     unix 0xffff8802f544e800       0t0   743004 type=STREAM ->INO=737278 4167,cinnamon-,21u
firefox 6261 chazelas   14u     unix 0xffff8801474b3c00       0t0   737279 type=STREAM ->INO=737280 6261,firefox,15u
firefox 6261 chazelas   15u     unix 0xffff8801474b7c00       0t0   737280 type=STREAM ->INO=737279 6261,firefox,14u
firefox 6261 chazelas   34u     unix 0xffff8801d0d01800       0t0   741294 type=STREAM ->INO=743006 4244,dbus-daem,57u
firefox 6261 chazelas   45u     IPv4             741950       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:44232->host24-rangeA-akamai-aanp.cdn.thlon.isp.sky.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 6261 chazelas   53u     unix 0xffff880178356800       0t0   741947 type=STREAM ->INO=743008 3575,Xorg,56u
firefox 6261 chazelas   60u     IPv4             743011       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:52760->a95-101-128-57.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 6261 chazelas   73u     IPv4             742158       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:54674->lhr35s01-in-f14.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 6261 chazelas   87u     IPv4             743521       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:33564->stackoverflow.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 6261 chazelas   91u     IPv4             743522       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:53940->93.184.220.29:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 6261 chazelas   92u     IPv4             742153       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:36836->151.101.65.69:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 6261 chazelas   94u     IPv4             742154       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:33716->192.0.73.2:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 6261 chazelas   96u     IPv4             742157       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:51166->lhr26s04-in-f234.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 6261 chazelas  113u     IPv4             744875       0t0      TCP UNKNOWN:43262->lhr35s01-in-f1.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

Answer (score 4):

With `ss`.

As an example, I have a pid from `proftpd`:

```
[root@ftp ~]# ps fax | grep proftpd
 7461 ?        Ss     1:46 proftpd: (accepting connections)
```

Now, grep the output of `ss` for that process id.

```
[root@ftp ~]# ss -nap | grep 7461
LISTEN     0      5            *:21         *:*      users:(("proftpd",7461,0))
```

Where:

- `-a`: Display all sockets
- `-n`: Do not resolve well known port numbers into names(`*:22` will become `*:ssh`)
- `-p`: Show process information

**Take care**. This approach can create some false positives, for example, if you have a pid 22, that can also be the tcp port where you `ssh` server is listening to.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, this will show the information you want:

```
netstat -46pan
```

But it will only show all process numbers if the command is run as root.
So, as root:

```
netstat -46pan | grep "$pid"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of `nethogs`, a CLI app that shows per-process network activity in real time. Technically this answer deviates a little from the OP's core question, but it can provide the information requested and then some. It's likely to be useful to many people interested in the question.

```
sudo apt install nethogs
sudo nethogs
```

The app appears as below, it updates the display every second:

```
NetHogs version 0.8.5-2build2

    PID USER     PROGRAM                                  DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
   4422 davidp.. /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                 wlp0s2      1.304       8.101 KB/sec
   6972 davidp.. ..sr/lib/slack/slack --type=utility --u  wlp0s2      0.000       0.000 KB/sec
      ? root     unknown TCP                                          0.000       0.000 KB/sec

  TOTAL                                                               1.304       8.101 KB/sec
```